# Replace the array element with the multiples of all other elements throughout the array with O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I have an array `arr = [3,4,2,5,6,8,2]`. 
Every element in the array has to be replaced with the multiples of all other elements in the array. 
e.g `index=0`, value `3` must be replaced with `4*2*5*6*8*2` and `index=3`, value `5` must be replaced with `3*4*2*6*8*2`. 
And this must be done in `O(n)`. 
I have solutions with `dequeue` and `stack` but i end up doing n*n-1 iterations resulting in `O(n^2)`. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

First, calculate the total Product of this array.
Then, for each element in the array divide by that value and assign the result to its position.
So the total product is done in O(n), the assignment is also done in O(n).

=> ALG: O(2*n) = O(n)

Comment: And what if the array contains one zero?

Comment: well, thats a good point. one could loop once through the array and determine if there is non, one or multiples zeros: if non, the above solution hold. if multiple, all entries are zero. if there is only one zero, just multiply all entries except zero und assign the value in there. all others are zero nontheless

Comment: Had the same doubt of a zero occurance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Form two arrays: one cumulative product from the left, and one cumulative product from the right. They can each be constructed in O(2*n).
2. Take the left-cumulative product for the element to the left and multiply by the right-cumulative product to the right. That takes O(n).

Something like:

```
leftCumulative[1]=1;
for(j=2;j<=n;++j) leftCumulative[j]=leftCumulative[j-1]*arr[j];
rightCumulative[n]=1;
for(j=n-1;j>=1;--j) rightCumulative[j]=arr[j]*rightCumulative[j+1];

arr[1]=rightCumulative[2];
arr[n]=leftCumulative[n-1];
for(j=2;j<=n-1;++j) arr[j]=leftCumulative[j-1]*rightCumulative[j+1];
```

It is possible to use less extra memory, and make the loop cleaner, but this solves the stated problem. It even works if multiplication is non-commutative!

Comment: *"It even works if multiplication is non-commutative!"* I know that you mean it even works for other operations which aren't necessarily commutative, but this statement is quite amusing if taken literally. This solution is nice, anyway, because it doesn't require handling special cases for how many zeroes are in the array. +1

Comment: i suppose you mean ++j in line 2 and --j in line 4?

Answer (score 0):

Using java,

```
  int[] arr = {3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 8, 2};

  int wholeProduct = arr[0];   //  wholeProduct = arr[0] * arr[1] * ... * arr[n-1]
  for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
     wholeProduct *= arr[i];

  for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
     arr[i] = wholeProduct/arr[i];
```

Same technique described by @Lecagy.

Please Note, when the contains many elements, the **wholeProduct** may not contains the result, you need to change the type to **long** or **BigInteger**.